# Transparent, Click-Through Forms but can move byTitle bar

Tags: c#, winforms

i was picked some code, implement a Topmost, Transparent and Click-Though Form via code:

```
public enum GWL
{
    ExStyle = -20
}

public enum WS_EX
{
    Transparent = 0x20,
    Layered = 0x80000
}

public enum LWA
{
    ColorKey = 0x1,
    Alpha = 0x2
}

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowLong")]
public static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, GWL nIndex);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLong")]
public static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, GWL nIndex, int dwNewLong);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetLayeredWindowAttributes")]
public static extern bool SetLayeredWindowAttributes(IntPtr hWnd, int crKey, byte alpha, LWA dwFlags);

protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnShown(e);
    int wl = GetWindowLong(this.Handle, GWL.ExStyle);
    wl = wl | 0x80000 | 0x20;
    SetWindowLong(this.Handle, GWL.ExStyle, wl);
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(this.Handle, 0, 128, LWA.Alpha);
}
```

The problems here, all of form is cannot click on it (cause by click-though code), how to do the Click-though Form but except Title Bar ( User can click on Titlebar To move form to other position )?

i have a method, this code can solve my problem ( Click-though ), but Text in form is have not its opacity, and Title bar also not opacity.

```
this.BackColor = Color.Magenta;
  this.TransparencyKey = Color.Magenta;
```

Comment: IMAGE for Example form here http://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0SdD.jpg

Comment: What do you mean *...but Text in form is have not its opacity, and Title bar also not opacity*? You **can not** click something that is not visible!

Comment: Sorry for my bad English, I mean Text and Title bar in form like opacity=1, i want to text and Title bar have opacity 0.5 with second code

Comment: Set `opacity`(in properties) of your form `50%`

Comment: thanks, but Text in form cannot click-though